# less/sass with php

Tags: php, sass, less

I am a front end developer and have recently considered using SASS or LESS for CSS development.

However I do not use Ruby and I don't want to rely on users having JavaScript active. Does anyone have any tips for using SASS or LESS using PHP projects?

Comment: You should try lessphp - http://leafo.net/lessphp/. It's extra overhead if you just use php.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8411274/762449

Comment: **[php-sass](https://github.com/panique/php-sass)** and if you use Laravel **[laravel-sass](https://github.com/panique/laravel-sass)**.

Comment: You can implement Libsass into your php build as a dynamic extension  [LibSassPHP](https://github.com/shlomohass/LibSassPHP) does exactly that it supports both indented syntax (SASS) and SCSS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install Ruby. Install SASS. Use SASS.

It outputs static files, so you just upload them like any other CSS as part of your build/publish process.

Comment: Yep, the ruby is run on your computer, and produces CSS files. Your user just gets the CSS file as normal. No ruby required on the server.

Comment: this creates a huge gap between writing and testing, which completely ruins the workflow.

Comment: @hugo_leonardo If you use sass in watch mode, that gap instantly dissapears http://stackoverflow.com/a/2647819/1820

Comment: the answer that @Cheekysoft links to is awesome. it expands on this accepted answer well. please read that one, sass newbies!! i know because i am a sass newbie myself.

Comment: Can I ask why this answer is accepted? Question was about less/sass in php, but using this solution require user to install Ruby... I agree - it's some way to achieve the goal, but I can't agree it's best.

Comment: @KevinLaity — I suppose they should use a text editor and operating system written in PHP too then?

Comment: @Quentin The question was of the form 'how do I..?' not 'should I..?' If the question was 'How do I use PHP as an operating system?' then you can give your best advice on how to use PHP as an operating system, or not answer.

Comment: @KevinLaity — The question is about using SASS or LESS in a PHP project, not specifically about using PHP to compile SASS or LESS.

Comment: @Quentin He specifically stated he 'does not use Ruby' which to me suggests he's looking for an answer that does not include the use of Ruby. But I suppose theres room for debate there and maybe a downvote was too harsh, I'll un-downvote this. (or I will if it gets edited, I guess SO now requires an edit.. weird)

Comment: -1 Developers don't always have permissions to install what they want on a server. Even if there's a workaround, such as setting up a duplicate test server with Ruby installed, compiling files, and sending them to the live server, then this is still a poor answer.

Answer (score 26):

Download the latest version of **lessphp** [here](http://leafo.net/lessphp/).

Here is an example on how I tried it:

```
<?php
require 'lessc.inc.php';

$less = new lessc('test.less');
file_put_contents('test.less.css', $less->parse());

?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Less CSS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.less.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>This isn't supposed to be black!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

And my test.less file:

```
@color : #33ddff;
.colorful(@textcolor : red){
    color : @textcolor;
}
h1{
    .colorful(@color);
}
```

It works for me, and it's php!

Comment: yeah real simple solution, here's how my journey to less has been started

Answer (score 10):

You now have two options written by me:

- LESS: http://leafo.net/lessphp/
- SCSS: http://leafo.net/scssphp/ (Only has SCSS syntax, not the indentation based SASS syntax)

Both are well documented. I encourage you to try them out and tell me if you have any trouble.

Comment: +1 (I'm currently using the SCSS module, since phpsass has no documentation)

Comment: @leafo : Are you planning to support SCSS 3.3? Any idea when we can expect it?

Comment: @leafo Is there a version of scssphp that works just like lessphp? I liked the compileToCacheFileOnCommand nature of lessphp's API.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this tutorial:
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-squeeze-the-most-out-of-less/

(4th entry when googling 'less php')

Comment: Yeah, forever! It was just to point out the difficulty of finding an answer.

Answer (score 2):

LESS PHP takes a lot of resources...okay lot is relative, but anyway, you should chache the output css. 
If you're on Mac, use [LESSapp](http://incident57.com/less/). If you're on Windows, use [dotLEss](http://www.dotlesscss.org/) (actually it's a library, which could be integrated in several .NET project, but **it has a small command-line compiler**, wich outputs a valid CSS file)

Answer (score 2):

As part of my job I do use sass with php.

You may try [PhamlP](http://code.google.com/p/phamlp/) as this is what I use. `PhamlP` is a port of `Haml` and `Sass` to `PHP`.

You may have the sass parser run every page load or you can have it cache the `css` it generates.

[Here is the same question question being asked.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218712/any-good-sass-parser-for-php) if you want to see more options

Answer (score 2):

You can use PhpLessDemandBridge for that: https://github.com/andyhausmann/PhpLessDemandBridge

You can simply use it in your Templates, like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"  href="css/engine/css.php?file=bootstrap.less" />
```

The Engine can be configured via config file, where you define your path the the less files and cache files.

By defining "css.php?file=bootstrap.less", you point the Engine to the bootstrap file, which import other less files e.g. Twitter Bootstrap or such.

I am using this for Magento, TYPO3 CMS and many more.

In the first line, i am including needed parts of Twitter Bootstrap - after that i am including my own theme and overrides.

Answer (score 2):

If you're working with WordPress, you should definitely check out [WP LESS](https://github.com/sanchothefat/wp-less). I All you need to do is specify a `.less` file with `wp_register_style` or `wp_enqueue_style` or even `add_editor_style`, and it compiles your LESS code into CSS code for you. It also caches the resulting CSS so you don't have the overhead of the LESS compiling on every page load.

Answer (score 1):

There's another less compiler available now: [less.php](https://github.com/oyejorge/less.php)

Answer (score 1):

I have http://leafo.net/scssphp/ on a few projects. It works well for me, here is what I do.

Install scssphp into lib/scssphp/

In .htaccess

```
#Sass Parser: anything /css/FILENAME.css -> FILENAME.scss
RewriteRule ^css/(.*).css?$ style.php/$1.scss [NC,L]
```

In root folder, I have style.php:

```
<?php
    require "lib/scssphp/scss.inc.php";
    $scss = new scssc();
    $scss->setFormatter("scss_formatter");
    $server = new scss_server("ui", null, $scss);
    $server->serve();       
?>
```

In my HTML, I use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
```

In /ui I have my file of actual SCSS code: /ui/style.scss

And everything just works. SCSSPHP just checks if the file needs to be recompiled and does it transparently, otherwise sends the cached version.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use PHP itself to dynamically generate your CSS??  Here are 10 good reasons why:

1. LESS provides 1 awkward, unfamiliar form of looping - while PHP provides 4 forms of familiar, native looping (do, while, for, foreach).
2. LESS provides 1 awkward, unfamiliar form of variables - while PHP provides 6 to 12 familiar, native data structures: variables, arrays, associative arrays/hash tables, arrays of arrays/multidimensional arrays, objects, and database record sets. And the Standard PHP Library also provides heaps, stacks, queues, maps, doubly linked lists, and fixed arrays.
3. LESS does't provide conditionals - while PHP offers 4 familiar, native forms of conditionals: if-then, if-then-else, case/switch, and the ternary operator.
4. LESS provides 1 awkward, unfamiliar form of including files (import) - while PHP provides 2 familiar, native forms: include and require.
5. LESS provides various awkward, unfamiliar forms of structuring your CSS - while PHP provides familiar, native, object-oriented forms of structuring your code.
6. LESS requires learning essentially a new programming language, and following it as it changes over time - while PHP leverages your existing knowledge.
7. LESS makes your code less readable and less consistent - while preprocessing CSS in PHP keeps your code consistent and makes it more readable.
8. LESS requires taking an extra "compilation"/preprocessing step and requires maintaining multiple versions of your CSS files - while PHP can either generate the CSS dynamically on-the-fly from a single source (if you're not concerned about performance) or it can generate a final "compiled"/preprocessed version just like a LESS preprocessor (if you're concerned about performance).
9. LESS requires downloading and installing a third-party preprocessor - while PHP already provides the functionality.
10. LESS can only be used for CSS - while PHP can be used to dynamically generate CSS, HTML, JavaScript, jQuery, etc.

CSS preprocessors like LESS and SASS may be a savior for desperate front-end developers with no access to back-end tools like PHP.  But for a PHP developer, these are counterproductive and less powerful.  In my humble opinion, this seems like buzzword mania and add-on mania gone amok.  PHP was designed to provide all of the functionality of LESS and a lot more.

Comment: I'm a PHP programmer myself. I prefer SCSS to LESS, because SCSS resembles a normal programming language far more than LESS. I prefer SCSS to PHP for generating CSS simple because throwing in PHP tags into your CSS code creates an unreadable mess. On the other hand, I don't like many of the design choices may be the core dev team... like their intent to break backwards compatibility for their `@import` statement. It makes me want to write my own pre-processor language... if I can find the time for it.

Comment: **Reading code is much harder than writing code**. You may argue PHP is far more powerful for making complex stylesheets, but, as @JohnSlegers said, it will be an unreadable mess and a nightmare to maintain.

Comment: 1. I have to share my code with a non-coder/frontend dev
2. I want my (S)CSS sources to resemble CSS as much as possible - I have no time to think about PHP while editing SCSS.
3. The major framework we use is written in SCSS anyway.

Comment: When you make a CSS file dynamic you have to deal with mimetypes and cache management. No thanks.

Comment: can't customize bootstrap and fontawesome with pure php so while i'd love to tis not as usefull

Comment: Just try to read a database to get information and produce CSS according to the data and you'll quickly understand why John Doe's answer is far from being stupid...